# Short story about a competition to become King for a day, after which the winner would be killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I don't remember much from the story, but what really marked me was that everyone on a planet competed in a competition to become King of the planet, yet the one that won would be killed afterwards. I also remember that murder was legal during the competition, and *I think* a conscious machine was behind it all.

It was a short story, part of a volume I read when I was a lot younger (would be at least 30 years old).

Comment: Elements of this sound like "Player of Games" by Iain M. Banks

Comment: It reminds of an episode of the Métal Hurlant Chronicles.

Comment: Just ordered the entire Iain M. Banks' "Culture" series, as the description made me quite curious. I will have to read it before i see if that's the one or not. Even if it is not, i believe it will be a good read.

Comment: If not for your belief that it was a short story, I'd be inclined to suggest Fred Saberhagen's novel *Berserker's Planet.*

Comment: There is an element of this in Guy Gavriel Kay's novel _[Tigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigana)_.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds similar to *[Man's Best Friend](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45846)* by Evelyn Smith published in Galaxy magazine and broadcast on the radio program X-minus One.

An AI in the palace would dictate someone to be the next Overlord; whose first job was to kill the current Overlord and take his place.

You can read the full text online [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/51050/51050-h/51050-h.htm)

Comment: Just finished reading it, but it's not the one i read years ago :(